# Integrate Angular2 project into Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, angular, build

I've developed a Spring maven rest api for my project. For the client side, I'm using Angular2 with typescript. As new to Angular, referred angular website for the development, using npm and lite-server.

**Now I need to make these two separate projects into a single project**, by integrating the html,js,css files into my maven project, to deploy it in Tomcat server.

**Project structure**

Client side

```
Project
|__ app
      |_ all app files
|__ node_modules
|__ typings
|__ index.html
|__ package.json
|__ style.css
|__ systemjs.config.js
|__ tsconfig.json
|__ typings.json
```

Server side

```
Project
|__ src/main
        |__ java
        |__ resources
        |__ webapp
                 |__index.html
|__ pom.xml
```

**All similar posts/blogs, i found suggest to update pom.xml with node etc. But what i need is,**

- Compile the angular-typescript project to js files.
- Produce a set of fully functional html,js,css files.
- Copy them to server webapp folder or whereever they must be.
- Running Spring maven project in Tomcat must display my client side index page
- Client must work (communicating with rest api) same way when they were two separate projects

How this can be done?

Run this command, `npm run build`, in angular project root folder to create a `dist` folder, containing production ready client side files. But got this error

> missing script build

.

Comment: The Solution for this problem can be found in the below post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors/44727035#44727035

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At last used **angular-cli**. `ng build --prod` creates a production ready build. Copied index.html and .js files under project folder in tomcat webapps (Or under Webcontent in eclipse).

Edited index.html as `<base href = ".">` and it worked fine

Comment: @MendonAshwini If question and answer helped you, please up vote them, so that it will reach more people quickly ( not only for me ;) )

Comment: Sure. I missed to upvote the question. Answer I upvoted already

Comment: I am trying to deploy my angular cli project via a similar method to an Oracle WebLogic server (I'm actually using the grunt-war npm to build a war to deploy). I've adjusted the `<base href = ".">` as you show above. After deploying the war file, I can hit the app from the url: `[weblogic IP]:[port]/[appname]` and if I just click on links the app works fine. However if I ever refresh a page or try to navigate to a specific page via a url, I get a 404 error. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: @ZackDeRose I've not much experience in this. Better you please ask a new question, someone in SO, who have a better understanding, can help you. Good luck!

Comment: @RamanujanR appreciate you looking out. I resolved the issue by building via the command `ng build --base-href /[app-name]/` and wrapping that up in a war file (via grunt). I also had to adjust my RouterModule import in my app.module.ts file to: `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutues, {useHase: true})` This will add a `/#/` between the app name and the path, but as I understand, that's pretty much unavoidable if you're putting an angular app out on a Tomcat or WebLogic.

Comment: @Ramanujan, Thanks, but , as you can see on deploying  dist folder (build folder) on tomcat server, app runs on http. How to run our app on https ?

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr The choice of HTTP/HTTPS is configured in server (tomcat or whatever). It has nothing to do with angular configuration or building process. The developer must contact the system administrator for this.

Comment: @Ramanujan , thanks, I need to configure my tomcat server for http/https.