# Spring mvc with angular 2 deployment on server

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I want to create a Spring MVC rest application for web browser, android and ios
For web browser, I am using angular2 and my web server is apache tomcat.
So I am confused that I need to put the angular code inside my Spring mvc appllication project directory or create a separate instance for angular.If I have to create separate instance for both then how I will deploy angular code to the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the both.

If you want to put the angular2 files to the tomcat then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40798898/1125284). This is might not straight forward.

If you want to deploy separately, I mean server(spring REST) and client(angular2) then angular2 app can deploy using the `ng` command or any web server like apache, nginx. You can look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/angular-2-and-spring-boot-development-environment) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in any of the ways.

---

But
with a SPA + REST technology stack, I prefer separating front end and
back end with rest api because static resources are best served from front-server. Since Front-End servers (e.g. nginx,apache2) are very powerful and since you can use Cache for static resources, you can manage with a single deployment of your static resources (which should be all HTML content, JS, CSS, Images).