# Deploy Angular2 App with baseurl

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli, tomcat8

I am new to **Angular2** Wep app development.

I created one **Angular2** app with use of **angular-cli,** now i want to deploy this app to my tomcat server.

I gave ng build and it create the dist folder for deployment. I copied all files inside the dist folder and create one folder inside the Tomcat webapps folder like **somename** and paste all files inside this **somename** folder. And i changed the **index.html** base href as /somename.

```
<base href="/somename">
```

if i run the app from server like **localhost:9000/somename**. it gives the error in console like file not error.

How can i solve the issue.

please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the **exact error message** to your question. What server are you using? Does it work on the server in the root path? Have you tried using `HashLocationStrategy`? (`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`)?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors

Answer (score 3):

Try setting base href as one of the following:

`<base href="./">`: This usually works well for starter packs, or beginner projects that do not have/use Angular Routers. It basically sets the `base` as whichever directory it is served from.

`<base href="/somename/>` (Note the ending `/`):
This worked well for me on IIS 8.5 -- more [details here](http://kichnan.github.io/acute-angular/deployment/iis/2017/03/19/deploy-angular-in-iis.html).

Also, on a related note, a minor piece of advise would be to use `ng build --base-href your-new-base-href` command instead of manually editing `index.html` everytime you build your app.

Comment: Just for the heck of it... you can further experiment with different values of base `href`, like "/", "", "somename", "somename/", "./", "./somename". It will give you a decent, practical understanding of how `<base>` works. Quick info on base tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try to build app like

ng build --base-href /myApp/

or

```
<base href="/myApp/">
```

Your dist folder content should be copied to "myApp" folder. Run the app from  tomcat server like **localhost:8080/myApp/**