# deploy Angular Cli app on ubuntu server

Tags: angular, deployment, server

My angular cli app works fine with mongodb locally. Locally, I run two services,

```
 node server.js
```

on port 3000, and

```
 ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json
```

on port 4200.

Now I tried to deploy it on an apache tomcat remote server. I have copied the content from the "/dist"  (after running "ng build --prod") folder to server under "apache-tomcat-8.0.47/webapps/", what else?

Open the browser, no data properly got from ":8080/api/models:1

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
```

"/api/models:1" should be from running "node server.js" , I guess. Where/how to "scp" "server.js" to server??

Thank you for your help.

This is not the same problem as "[Deploy Angular 2 App with Webpack to Tomcat - 404 Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors)", mine has server side.

Comment: So you deployed it to apache tomcat remote server, what's the issue...?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies he said those commands are ran locally.

Comment: Ok deleted comment

Comment: @penleychan sorry, I added more info.

Comment: Are you trying to serve your angular app in production with ng serve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy Angular 2 App with Webpack to Tomcat - 404 Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors)

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I just want to deploy my app on a linux server, not necessarily to be "ng serve"

Comment: The right way to do this is build the app (with ng build) and then serve the output (that is generated in the dist/ folder) under a webserver (Apache, NGinx, etc...). The built-in webserver from angular-cli is not meant to be used in production, it is for development. Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: @ChristianBenseler yeah, you are right, it is using the built-in webserver, ... I should reconsider the whole project

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Apache to redirect every request to `index.html` : on a "regular website", you load one page per URL.

With a single page application, everything is contained into the index file.

Since it's an API link that is the issue, you also need to run a node server. You launched the command correctly and that's great, but now you have to change it.

Serve your node server on another port (let's say 8081), change the URL in your `environment.ts` file to hit that one, and run `node server.js`

Comment: This is multiple pages app.  I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: only copy "server.js" to server? where?

Comment: Where you can ! Heroku can do it for you, or you can buy a Linux server to deploy your node server on it.