# Deploy Angular 7 project with Apache server with subfolder

Tags: angular, deployment, angular7

Deploy Angular 7 project with Apache server in subfolder

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.1
Node: 11.1.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.1
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.1
@angular/cli                      7.3.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.1
@schematics/angular               7.3.1
@schematics/update                0.13.1
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Flightslogic</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

App.routing:-

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',  redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent,  },
  { path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent,  },
  { path: 'products/fare-app', component: ProductFareAppComponent,  },
  { path: 'developer', component: ResourceDeveloperProgramComponent,  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Home page nav:

```html
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link waves-light" href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Home
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbWavesEffect  href="about-us">About</a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

I want to deploy to apache server with subdirectory. How can I achieve that.
For ex: http://www.example.com and the subdirectory is subdir. So I want to deploy to http://www.example.com/subdir. How can I achieve it.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors/50549890#50549890 ,  and if helpful please do upvote the answer.

Comment: I have tried with it. but when it will write  http://example.com/subdir, it will route to http://example.com/subdir/home and page will open, but if I write http://example.com/subdir/home manually it will give page not found error

Comment: then, in production mode, you have to include a `web.xml` file which will redirect 404 to index.html, and the normal angular routing will be available in the production mode.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I have solved this. By rewriting the .htaccess file
Rewrite .htaccess file as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /subdir/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

ng build --base-href=/subdir/ --deploy-url=/subdir/ --prod

Comment: But how did you get to /subdir/ in the first place ? `Alias`? ?

Comment: Setting the base href to the subdirectory worked for me. See  https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag